# MS Access - 2 combo boxes, one isn't updating

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have two combo boxes on a form. The first allows the user to search a record by name, and when a record is selected, all of the other controls on the form are updated. I don't remember how I did this, and I think it may have been through the wizard. But now I want to add a second combo box that allows users to search by address, but when an address is selected in this new combo box, the record does not update.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

And...

```
Private Sub Combo250_AfterUpdate()

Me.Requery

End Sub
```

And also a SearchForRecord Macro which searches for the First record with using this WHERE clause

```
="[ID] = " & Str(Nz(Screen.ActiveControl,0))
```

The two tables involved are Demographics and Addresses, and they are joined by the ID column.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the wizard to add the combobox and when the option shows "Find a record on my form based on the value I select in my combobox", choose that and continue through the wizard.

Manual code:

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst "Address='" & Me.cboAddress & "'"
    If Not .NoMatch Then
        Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I know I have seen that before but it's not showing as an option in the wizard now. Have you experienced this problem?

Comment: Also, I know this option doesn't display when the record source is empty, but I actually have multiple tables in the record source, so it should be displaying

Comment: @Jerry It seems that your form is based on an SQL string rather than a table or query, this will create the problem you are experiencing. You can either save the recordsource as a query and your wizard will work again or you can manually create the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should give the controls meaningful names like `cboSearchByAddress`.

I don't know how the SearchForRecord macro works, but you can change the code in the AfterUpdate event to:

```
Private Sub cboSearchByAddress_AfterUpdate()
  Me.Filter = "[ID]=" & Nz(cboSearchByAddress,0))
  Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

You might need to change `Nz(cboSearchByAddress,0))` to `Nz(cboSearchByAddress.Column(0),0))` depending on the settings of the combo box.